# Mongoose update nested schema

Tags: mongoose

I cannot find a working solution to update a nested Schema in Mongoose.

Schemas:

```
const boardSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    tasks: { type: [taskSchema] }
  },
)

const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    priority: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true }
  },
)

const Board = mongoose.model('Board', boardSchema)
const Task = mongoose.model('BoardTask', taskSchema)
```

How can I update a task inside of a `board.tasks` array? I've tried

```
const taskId = 'demo'
const taskUpdate = {title: 'Demo', priority: 0}

Board.findOneAndUpdate({ taskId: taskId }, taskUpdate)

taskSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(taskId, taskUpdate)

Board.findById(boardId).then(board => {
    BoardTask.findOneAndUpdate(board.taskId, taskUpdate)
})
```

I think I must be missing a point here, I am not even sure whether I should try to update it out of taskSchema or Task model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update a task saved inside Board model, you don’t need a Task collection and hence no need for a Task model. And update query would go something like this:-

```
const getUpdate = (update) => {
  const updateQuery = {};
  Object.keys(update).forEach(key => {
    updateQuery[`tasks.$.${key}`] = update[key];
  });
  return updateQuery;
}

const update = {
  title: "newtitle",
  taskId: "22"
}

Board.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: boardId, “tasks._id”: taskId },
  {$set: getUpdate(update) }
);
```

However that said I would recommend you to have a different Task collection and save reference of parent Board id in the task.

Comment: the thing is it's not working. Mongoose is not returning any error but the object is not updated.

Comment: What is returned from this query?

Comment: `null` comes as a successful response

Comment: when I do `Task.find({})` it returns an empty array although there are documents stored

Comment: No null means no document was found with that id. You have to perform find on Task model and please check the id is correct when you are finding that document. Task.find() should return all documents. There might be some bug. Please share the code where you are calling Task.find

Comment: Now I am wondering - to use any method on a `Task` (`find()`, `findOneAndUpdate()` etc) do I also need to create a document via `Task.create()`? Because I've created it by pushing an object to a `Board` - `Board.findByIdAndUpdate(boardId, {$push: {newTask}})`. Using `Task.create()` would create a new collection in my db but I don't want to have a new collection, I want to keep those objects in a document in a boards collection.

Comment: Ohh now there’s the problem. Any queries on Task looks for the documents on the Tasks collection and inside Board. Your schema is wrong then and you don’t need the task model. But there is a catch, the right way to do this which will also be easier is to create a different Task collection and save a reference of the parent board in that. Thing is mongodb has document size limit of 16mb and saving all the task which I assume will be infinite and are not limited will fill up that space eventually. Also you will find it difficult to perform simple queries quite challenging with that structure.

Comment: I gave a simplified code here in the question but indeed, I have a `boards` and `tasks` collections, and the `task` I was asking about here is only a reference to a document stored in a `tasks` collection. So that's indeed how you have described it. The code in your answer works almost fine, it updates the object it's supposed to update, but deletes some of other properties. In a task I have  taskId, columnId, priority and title, and when I update it with `{title: 'test'}` the title gets updated, priority stays fine, but columnId and taskId are gone. I don't know where should I post my code.

Comment: If you want to update just a single field just target that field in the update and then it won’t change other fields. Check the updated answer

Comment: yes, it works fine if I want to update only one value, but it may happen that multiple properties need to be updated.

Comment: I've found this solution but it's not the most convenient, would require some kind of additional looping through an object `{ $set: { 'tasks.$.title': 'aaa', 'tasks.$.taskId': 'bbb' } }`

Comment: Yes you would need to do some extra work to create an update object. Check the updated answer. And this is what I was talking about that dealing with this structure makes simple update functions quite challenging.

Comment: cool, that is working. But you say that this is the best solution if the task here is only supposed to store the data that a board needs to know about this task, and is referencing to a task from a tasks collection? If so, I am fine with that ;)

Comment: Are you going to have an infinite number of tasks inside a Board?

Comment: no, I plan to restrict it, but if it's gonna be an infinite number then it's not a good solution?

Comment: No, see mongodb is pretty awesome to perform queries over multiple documents even if the number is billion because of indexing. But embedding many documents inside a document is not a very good idea as it would cause many performance issues as the list grows and also simple operations like update and delete and even find will become quite challenging as we saw. And on above that mongodb has document size limit of 16mb which will eventually run out as the list of tasks grows and then you are gonna face some serious problems.

Comment: Look at this blog post by mongodb team on best schema design practices, it will also make things clear https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: thank you very much :) you were really helpful (again!)